# Error with Importing Auth0-lock in Svelte App

Tags: javascript, auth0, svelte, svelte-3, auth0-lock

I m quite beginning with svelte and more a backend end developer than javascript. I see few people using Auth0 with svelte/sapper, when I try to import an npm `auth0-lock` package I have got `events not defined` error but no error if I link the javascript in html header, what is the way to import `auth0-lock` correctly ?

the error is thrown in main.js and I just wanted to add :

```js
  import Auth0Lock from "auth0-lock";

  // // Initializing our Auth0Lock
  let lock = new Auth0Lock(
    "xxxxxxxxxxxxx",
    "xxxxxxxxxx.auth0.com"
  );

  login = () => {
    lock.show();
  };
```

`Uncaught ReferenceError: events is not defined  at main.js:8` error

Comment: Are you able to import other packages successfully?

Comment: Where have you added this? If `auth0-lock` only supports browser environment, it will crash if Sapper tries to run it in Node.

Comment: @DanWoda yes i was able to get something working with `auth0-js`

Comment: @rixo in front end